# Quick info documentation missing for .NET types in VS Code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a new laptop and made new Godot Mono project (it might be worth mentioning).
Everything works fine except that there is no documentation for anything in the System namespace. You can see it works but there is no documentation for System.Collections.Generic.Stack:

[image]

On my old laptop, the stuff was just there.
I also installed mono and dotnet sdk i think 6.0

I am also using vs code and have all the extensions i had on my old laptop including the c# xml documentation comments.

Comment: You tagged your question "c#", ".net", "documentation" and "godot", but your question has nothing to do with any of them. It is just a question about VSCode. So in order to get good answers, it might be wise to re-tag your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so its working now turns out that i had to install the english language pack in the visual studio installer.
And i thought the language packs where just there for translating the options and buttons... but yeah.

Comment: Please can you provide some more details. Do I need to reinstall vscode?